# Postdoc delayed decision! Possible reasons?

Tags: application, united-states, job

I have been interview 2 weeks ago for a postdoc. The panel said that they will reply early next week and its already two weeks passed since the interview. I am wondering if i should wait more or should send an email? 
Interview was conducted two times because one of the committee member was busy in first day and was not able to join. The first interview was actually very good and the second interview with with this professor was not that good as the first was. Is he holding back the decision?
I have also noticed that one of my reference letter is not yet delivered, so I asked this professor and he said he will forward in 1-2 days. Could this be a reason of delay? Or 2 reference are enough to establish decision?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the delay could possibly cause you to miss another opportunity elsewhere, then it would be a good idea to follow up. However, if that is not the case, then patience is suggested. It hasn't been very long and people often miss deadlines even when they don't mean to. It is a busy time of year for most academics.

The question about the number of references is too local to comment on here. There may be a local rule, but certainly not a global one.